# How to parse data using XMLPull Parsing in android

Tags: android

How i can parse data from the url using XMLPull parsing

Here is url:  "http://demo.codeofaninja.com/AndroidXml/sample.xml

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Simple tutorial link](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-XMLPullParser-tutorial). Example:

```
//sample XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<employees>  
    <employee>  
        <id>1</id>  
        <name>Sachin</name>  
        <salary>50000</salary>        
    </employee>  
    <employee>  
        <id>2</id>  
        <name>Nikhil</name>  
        <salary>60000</salary>    
    </employee>  
</employees> 

//Sample Helper Class
public class XmlPullParserHandler {  
    private List<Employee> employees= new ArrayList<Employee>();  
    private Employee employee;  
    private String text;  

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {  
        return employees;  
    }  

    public List<Employee> parse(InputStream is) {  
           try {  
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();  
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);  
            XmlPullParser  parser = factory.newPullParser();  

            parser.setInput(is, null);  

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();  
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {  
                String tagname = parser.getName();  
                switch (eventType) {  
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:  

                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("employee")) {  
                        // create a new instance of employee  
                        employee = new Employee();  
                    }  
                    break;  

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:  
                    text = parser.getText();  
                    break;  

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:  
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("employee")) {  
                        // add employee object to list  
                        employees.add(employee);  
                    }else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {  
                        employee.setId(Integer.parseInt(text));  
                    }  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {  
                        employee.setName(text);  
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("salary")) {  
                        employee.setSalary(Float.parseFloat(text));  
                    }   
                    break;  

                default:  
                    break;  
                }  
                eventType = parser.next();  
            }  

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {e.printStackTrace();}   
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  

        return employees;  
    }  
}
```

As your given link, you need change `Start_Tag` to `owner` and in`End_Tag` change to `name`,`age`,`email`. It is pretty easy, right?